# Error in onChange of an ion-range in ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have the following html

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-range min="5" max="300" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="contrast" color="secondary" ionChange=“changeRange(contrast)”>
          <ion-icon range-left small name="contrast"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon range-right name="contrast"></ion-icon>
        </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

the result is:

[image]

and this is the triggered method :

```
changeRange(valor){
    console.log(valor.value);

  }
```

Where, as you can see, I use the ionChange to execute the changeRange method. But when I run it, I get the following error.

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not find the solution for this way of using the range.
But I was able to achieve the goal by changing in this way.

```
   <ion-range min="20" max="300" color="secondary" (ionChange)="changeRange($event)">
          <ion-icon range-left small name="contrast">20</ion-icon>
          <ion-icon range-right name="contrast">300</ion-icon>
        </ion-range>
```

and

```
  changeRange(valor){

    console.log(valor.value);

  }
```

Comment: it was not working for me until i add "$event" as parameter ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning & it doesn't affect your application. You can just ignore it or you can try another plugin for the range component

Comment: if it affects, I think, because it does not execute the method.